# How to limit the number of words when reading a line from standard input?

Tags: java

I am new to Stackoverflow and this is my first time asking a question. I have searched my problem thoroughly, however, could not find an appropriate answer. I am sorry if this has been asked. Thank you in advance.

#### The question is from Hyperskill.com as follows:

Write a program that reads five words from the standard input and outputs each word in a new line.
First, you need to print all the words from the first line, then from the second (from the left to right).

#### Sample Input 1:

This Java course
is adaptive

#### Sample Output 1:

This
Java
course
is
adaptive

#### My trial to solve it

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* I have not initialized the "userInput" String.
         * I know that String is immutable in Java and
         * if I initialize it to an empty String ""
         * and read a String from user.
         * It will not overwrite to the "userInput" String.
         * But create another String object to give it the value of the user input,
         * and references the new String object to "userInput".
         * I didn't want to waste memory like that.
         */
        String userInput;
        String[] userInputSplitFirstLine = new String[3];
        String[] userInputSplitSecondLine = new String[2];
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        userInput = scan.nextLine();
        userInputSplitFirstLine = userInput.split("\\s+");
        userInput = scan.nextLine();
        userInputSplitSecondLine = userInput.split("\\s+");
        for(String firstLineSplitted: userInputSplitFirstLine) {
            System.out.println(firstLineSplitted);
        }
        for(String secondLineSplitted: userInputSplitSecondLine) {
            System.out.println(secondLineSplitted);
        }
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

If you try the sample input above, the output will match the sample output above. However, if you write more than 3 words to the first line and/or more than 2 words to the second line, the `userInputSplitFirstLine` array of size 3 will store more than 3 words. Same goes with the `userInputSplitSecondLine` array also. My **first question** is how can an array of size 3 (userInputSplitFirstLine) and an array of size 2 (userInputSplitSecondLine) can hold more than 3 and 2 elements, respectively? My **second question** is that how can I restrict/limit the number of words that the user can insert in a line; for example, the first line **only** accepts 3 words and the second line **only** accepts 2 words?

#### Also the answer to this question suggested by Hyperskill.com is as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
 
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
 
        String wordOne = scanner.next();
        String wordTwo = scanner.next();
        String wordThree = scanner.next();
        String wordFour = scanner.next();
        String wordFive = scanner.next();
 
        System.out.println(wordOne);
        System.out.println(wordTwo);
        System.out.println(wordThree);
        System.out.println(wordFour);
        System.out.println(wordFive);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not a proper answer to your first question, but: you can't, the size of an array is fixed, and you can't change it if you've already declared it. you'd need to declare that array again, or extend it by creating other array.

you're overengineering this problem, you don't need to save the words in memory, you just need to print them. scan a word, print, that's what the example below is showing you.

Comment: > how can an array of size 3 (userInputSplitFirstLine) and an array of size 2 (userInputSplitSecondLine) can hold more than 3 and 2 elements, respectively?

It cant, userInput.split creates a new array whose size depends on the number of splits it it gets, which in your case is the number of words. The two arrays or size 2 and 3 that you created are discarded without use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do the work. Don't hesitate to ask, if you have some questions.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final StringBuffer line = new StringBuffer();
        final StringBuffer words = new StringBuffer();

        try (final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                final String currentLine = sc.nextLine();
                line.append(currentLine).append(System.lineSeparator());
                for (final String word : currentLine.split("\\s+")) {
                    words.append(word).append(System.lineSeparator());
                }
            }
        } finally {
            System.out.println(line.toString());
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(words.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use next method of scanner object to read string and then it can be printed easily on new line.

```
while(true){
            if(scanner.hasNext()){
                System.out.println(scanner.next());
            }
            else{
                break;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> My first question is how can an array of size 3 (userInputSplitFirstLine) and an array of size 2 (userInputSplitSecondLine) can hold more than 3 and 2 elements, respectively?

The array here:

```
String[] userInputSplitFirstLine = new String[3];
```

is not the same one as the one you got from `split`:

```
userInputSplitFirstLine = userInput.split("\\s+");
```

When you do the above assignment, the old array that was in there is basically "overwritten", and now `userInputSplitFirstLine` refers to this new array that has a length independent of what the old array had. `split` *always* return a new array.

> My second question is that how can I restrict/limit the number of words that the user can insert in a line; for example, the first line only accepts 3 words and the second line only accepts 2 words?

It really depends on what you mean by "restrict". If you just want to check if there are exactly three words, and if not, exit the program, you can do this:

```
userInputSplitFirstLine = userInput.split("\\s+");
if (userInputSplitFirstLine.length != 3) {
    System.out.println("Please enter exactly 3 words!");
    return;
}
```

You can do something similar with the second line.

If you want the user to be unable to type more than 3 words, then that's impossible, because this is a command line app.

By the way, the code in the suggested solution works because `next()` returns the next "word" (or what we generally think of as a word, anyway) by default.

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help you!

```
    public class pratice1 {
    public static void main (String[]args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = sc.nextLine();
    String input1 = sc.nextLine();
    char[]a =input.toCharArray();
    char[]a1 = input1.toCharArray();
    System.out.println(input +""+ input1);
    int a2=0;
    if(input!=null) {
    for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++) {
        if(a[i]==' ') { 
            a2=i;
            for(int j=0;j<a2;j++) {
                System.out.println(a[i]);
                a2=0;
            }
        }
        else System.out.print(a[i]);
    }System.out.println("");
    for(int i=0;i<input1.length();i++) {
        if(a1[i]==' ') {    
            a2=i;
            for(int j=0;j<a2;j++) {
                System.out.println(a1[i]);
                a2=0;
            }
        }
        else System.out.print(a1[i]);
    }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem:

> Write a program that reads five words from the standard input and
> outputs each word in a new line.

This was my solution:

```
while(scanner.hasNext()){
      System.out.println(scanner.next());
}
```